# Linking to libstdc++ version which has been used on the build system

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have prepared a simple c++14 example which contains a generic lambda:

```
auto glambda = [](auto a) { return a; };
```

I have used gcc 4.9.2 (libstdc++.so.6.0.20) to built that program. Here is **ldd** output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffca3d14000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fcc6062d000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fcc60417000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcc601f9000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcc5fe2f000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fcc5fb27000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcc6093c000)
```

When I run that program on the other system (virtual machine) which is equipped with gcc 4.6.3 (libstdc++.so.6.0.16) it works. Some programs don't start on the other system because there is not appropriate libstdc++. I have guessed that my program will not work because it uses c++14 feature which is not supported by gcc 4.6.3. How does it work ? When a program need link to libstdc++ which has been used on the build system ?

Comment: Lambdas are a language feature and have nothing to do with libstc++. Also from what I've heard  (not tested myself) gcc troes to stay binary compatible with previous versions for as long as possible.

Comment: Could you give me some example when a program will need link to libstdc++.so.6.0.20 ?

Comment: Linking to libstdc++ should become necessary, whenever you use a function or class that is not completely implemented in a header or one of the other "standard libraries " unfortunately, I don't have any Idea what those are, not to mention which is specific to that particular version.