# When a program has to link to libstdc++ version which is using on build machine?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, libstdc++

I have built some example c++ application using gcc 4.9.2 (libstdc++.so.6.0.20). I can run that program on a virtual machine which is equipped with gcc 4.6.3 ((libstdc++.so.6.0.16). Sometimes an application can't be run on the environment which differ from the build environment (for example libstdc++.so.6.0.16 vs libstdc++.so.6.0.20). When a program has to link to libstdc++ version which is using on build machine ? Could you give me some examples (with source code) ?

Comment: Is this an interview question?

Comment: No, I just can't find any answer. Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550237/linking-to-libstdc-version-which-has-been-used-on-the-build-system